# rails5 mongoid belongs_to/has_many data member not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, has-many, belongs-to

I have 2 classes feed.rb and ad.rb
Ad has_many Feed
Feed belongs_to Ad

```
class Feed
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :ad , optional: true

  before_save :generate_timestamp
  validates_presence_of :name

  field :name, type: String
  field :insertdate, type: DateTime
  field :addata, type: Hash

  def generate_timestamp
    self.insertdate = DateTime.now
  end  
end

class Ad
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :feed

  before_save :generate_timestamp
  validates_presence_of :name

  field :name, type: String
  field :insertdate, type: DateTime
  field :creative, type: String

  def generate_timestamp
    self.insertdate = DateTime.now
  end  
end
```

In the controller, it saves the ad as new object with list of Feeds

```
def addad
    @feeds = Feed.all
    if request.post?
        ad = Ad.new
        ad.name = params['name']
        ad.creative = params['creative']
        ad.feed << @feeds
        render plain: ad.inspect
        ad.save
    end
end
```

When I check the DB and print out ad object, there is no feed attribute

```
#<Ad _id: 58a11ef023040c07963ef885, name: "this is testing", insertdate: nil, creative: "Sample">
```

Is there anything I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are use mogodb(mogoid) then you have to specify association in **different manner** like below

**class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :content
  field :published_on, :type => Date
  validates_presence_of :name
  embeds_many :comments
  referenced_in :author
end**

**please go thought this link for better understanding
http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid**

Comment: Thanks for the reply
However, I am not using embedded_in, I am going to use belongs_to, has_many, i.e. break into 2 collections

Comment: Ok got it,Try this.

**class Feed
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :ad 
end**

**class Ad
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :feeds
end**

also try this one.

**class Feed
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ads
end**

**class Ad
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :feeds
end**

Comment: Thanks
I solved it and the method is same as your 2nd one